# I cannot access XML data using LINQ to XML from a file

Tags: c#

I have the following XML in a file called contents.xml that is in the data directory in my C drive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <feed xml:base="http://datacenter1.table.core.windows.net/" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" 
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title type="text">TestContents</title>
    <entry>
        <title type="text" />
    <author>
        <name />
        </author>
        <link rel="edit" title="TestContents" />
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:PartitionKey>0100000</d:PartitionKey>
                <d:Text>xx</d:Text>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title type="text" />
        <updated />
```

I need to get the values of the `<d:Text>` so I created this console application:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\data\contents.xml");
           var q = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("entry")
              select (string)c.Element("link") ;
           Console.WriteLine(q);
       }

    }
}
```

But I have two problems. Firstly the console shows but then disappears before I can see the output. Second if I look at q in the debugger it says "enumeration returns no results".

What's the best way that I can use to get what I really need which is the values of the many `<d:Text>` ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I updated the question. Thanks for pointing out what was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Problem: After Console.WriteLine(q) line, you can write Console.ReadLine(). So result will be displayed until you press "Enter".

Second Problem: If you want all values in a list then u can do q.ToList()

Comment: Thanks. I still have some questions so I will ask in a different question so I can mark your answer valid.

Comment: Don't repost for the same problems.